# Downloading mp4 file from its link using javascript (not using node.js if possible)

Tags: javascript

i am making a tiny project,
so i have a video link on the internet and i want to download it to my computer using javascript.

here is a example video link:

```
https://youtube.com/shorts/ypoVptcePig?feature=share
```

well i tried to use,

```
<a href='url' download> Download </a>
```

and

```
a href='url' download='filename.mp4'> Download </a>
```

when i click to the link, it opens the video on the browser if the extension is mp4
if extension is gp3 it downloads it normally.

i have encountered a few ways but they all used node.js(like download.js)
i know its a good thing but i wanted to ask in case there is a solution without using node.js!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr: Can't be done.

---

The URL you have doesn't point to a video, it points to a webpage that embeds a video player.

The `download` attribute is only supported for Same Origin links.

The usual work around for the same origin limit is to fetch the URL using Ajax, and then generate a `data:` scheme URL, then create an `a` element and click it dynamically. This won't work because YouTube does not use [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) to grant you permission to fetch the resource using Ajax (and even if they did, you're still working on the URL to an HTML document not a video).

---

People downloading videos from YouTube do so *outside the browser* (the results could be proxied to a browser if desired). It's difficult but various libraries exist for various programming languages, the authors of which try to keep up with YouTube's changing backend.

(And this doesn't even get into the legal implications of what you are attempting to do).